# How to find second max element in an array in one iteration?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, max, array-algorithms

I need the second maximum element in an unsorted array in one iteration.
eg:  the array is 3 9 8 2 0 -4 87 45 3 2 1 0
The answer should be 45 , its very simple to find max element in one iteration , but how to find the second max in the same iteration , or constant time after the fort iteration of the array.

Comment: Exactly the same way, you just store 2 elements.

Comment: BTW in the general case to find kth largest element in the array, you can maintain a min-heap consisting of k elements from the array. After the array traversal, the heap shall contain k largest elements from the array and if you start emptying the heap, the elements shall pop out in ascending order. Complexity shall be O(n + klogk).

Answer (score 2):

```
for each element:
  if element is bigger than max, max shifts to second-max, element becomes max
  else if element is bigger than second-max, element becomes second-max
```

Comment: @SchmitzIT: Pseudocode is still code, please do not reformat it as text.

Answer (score 2):

```
int sz = arr.size();
assert(sz >= 2);
int maxElem = arr[0];
int secElem = arr[1];
if (maxElem < secElem) swap(maxElem, secElem);

for (int i = 2; i < sz; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > maxElem) {
        secElem = maxElem;
        maxElem = arr[i];
    } else if (arr[i] == maxElem) {
        secElem = maxElem;
    } else if (arr[i] < maxElem && arr[i] > secElem)) {
        secElem = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, except the fact that you don't need the second case, nor the first check in the third case. If `arr[i] == maxElem`, then `secElem = maxElem` is equivalent to `secElem = arr[i]`, which your third case handles just fine (or would, if you just put `arr[i] <= maxElem`, instead of `<`. But then you don't even need that, because of `else if`: the case where `!(arr[i] <= maxElem)` is eliminated in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

```
function MathLib()
{
    this.getSecondMax=function(args)
    {
        var max = 0;
        var secondMax = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
        {
            if(arguments[i]>max)
            {
                secondMax = max;
                max = arguments[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if(secondMax<arguments[i])
                {
                    secondMax = arguments[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return secondMax;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding some discussion rather than just code snippets.